# Why does my current-client service get rebuilt everytime the URL is changed in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a `current-client` service in Ember that is designed to pull the current user's information from the database and store it inside the service so that it can be used throughout the application. As long as I click on the navigation menu links, the current user information is preserved. But, when changing the URL in the address bar, the current user gets wiped out and the service has to go back and get the information again.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it from happening?

**Update:** I am using the authenticationMixins from Ember-Simple-Auth. Ideally, the solution provided will not impact this. For example, when the client is authenticated and logged in, if they try to navigate to the Login page then they should just be routed to the Index page, instead. Alternatively, if the unauthenticated client attempts to navigate to a protected page by just typing in the URL, then the application should authenticate the user and then route them to the page that they were originally trying to navigate to (without forcing the user to re-navigate).

**Update 2:** Specifically, the information that is being wiped out is whether the client has successfully completed their 2FA (i.e., `isTwoFactorAuthenticated` goes from True to False). This impacts the navigation menu that we are drawing based on whether the client is both authenticated and 2FA completed. In other words, the navigation menu is wrong because it makes the client look like they are logged out even though they are not.

**Service:** Current-client.js

```
import Service, { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({

    store: service('store'),

    isTwoFactorAuthenticated: false,

    twoFactorCodeSendMethod: null,

    client: null,

    loadCurrentClient() {

        this.get('store').queryRecord('client', {me: true})
        .then((client) => {

            this.set('client', client);
        });
    },
});
```

**Route:** Application.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Route.extend({

    session: service('session'),
    currentClient: service('current-client'),

    beforeModel() {

        this._super(... arguments);
        this.loadCurrentClient();
    },

    activate() {

        this._super(...arguments);

        document.body.classList.add('gray-bg');
    }, 

    init() {

        this._super(... arguments);

        this.get('session').on('authenticationSucceeded', () => {

            this.loadCurrentClient();

            this.get('currentClient').set('twoFactorCodeSendMethod', null);
            this.get('currentClient').set('isTwoFactorAuthenticated', false);
        }),

        this.get('session').on('invalidationSucceeded', () => {

            this.get('currentClient').set('client', null);
            this.get('currentClient').set('isTwoFactorAuthenticated', false);
            this.get('currentClient').set('twoFactorCodeSendMethod', null);

            window.location.replace('/clients/login');
        });
    },

    loadCurrentClient() {

        if(this.get('session').get('isAuthenticated')) {

            this.get('currentClient').loadCurrentClient();
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: doesnt changing url in address bar loads the whole app by design?

Comment: Are you looking to prevent the service from reloading? Or just to prevent a network call to reload client data?

Comment: @jrjohnson The later: prevent the network call to reload client data? Ideally, this should not impact the authenticationMixins from Ember Simple Auth. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `ember-simple-auth` already you can use the session service to [store/cache the data](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#the-session-service). This will tie it to authentication so when the user logs out the data is also removed. By default `ember-simple-auth` stores [session data in local storage](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#session-stores) which persists even when the browser is closed you may need to customize this to fit your requirements.

```
import Service, { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
  session: service(),
  store: service(),

  isTwoFactorAuthenticated: computed('session.data.isTwoFactorAuthenticated', {
    get() {
      return this.session.data.isTwoFactorAuthenticated || false;
    },
    set(key, value) {
      this.session.set('data.isTwoFactorAuthenticated', value);
      return value;
    }
  }),

  twoFactorCodeSendMethod: null,

  client: null,

  loadCurrentClient() {
    if (this.session.data.client) {
      this.client = this.session.data.client;
      return;
    }

    this.get('store').queryRecord('client', {me: true})
     .then((client) => {
       this.set('client', client);
       this.session.set('data.client', client);
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: I fear I may have explained the problem incorrectly. The problem is that the isTwoFactorAuthenticated is getting reset to false when the client either refreshes or tries to enter a URL in the navigation bar. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer a bit to show saving more information to the session data store. I don't advice using a computed property setter in this way, but I think it was the clearest way to update my answer. You could bypass having your own service and just get/set the data on the session wherever you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will check and confirm tomorrow since it is late now and I have left the office. However, I am curious to know what alternative you would recommend since you dont recommend doing it this way? Perhaps post it as a 2nd answer? Open to any and all solutions.

Comment: I would just store it in the session service directly. Or store it in this service but add a setIsTwoFactorAuthenticated() method. Computed property getters are an anti-pattern and are likely to be an upgrade hassle at home point, but if you're current code is relying on being able to get/set this property on this service it's the easiest path forward.